# postgres no suitable driver found

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea, tomcat, jdbc

Проблема: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc.postgresql://localhost:5432/first_db

IDE: IntellijIdea Ultimate 2020.1

БД: postgresql

Проект на git: https://github.com/Afler/SpringMCVAppTest.git

**Ветка crud_dao_branck крайний коммит**

Сервер: tomcat 9.0.43

Что пробовал: Читал все аналогичные вопросы. Качал .jar файл jdbc драйвера, помещал в tomcat_directory_name/lib, не помогло

Примечание: имеется другое приложение на tomcat 8.5.63, подключается к аналогичной бд только с драйвером в /lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил

Важное уточнение: для конфигурации подключения я использовал объект DriverManagerDataSource из библиотеки org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.
В документации к которому есть следующее замечание **NOTE**: [image: Читай NOTE]

Этот объект используется в первую очередь для доступа к предварительно зарегистрированным JDBC драйверам. Мой драйвер ранее не использовался для подключения к БД ни разу. Переписал подключение с помощью JDBC на самом низком уровне, успешно подключился, затем вернул исходный код, всё заработало.